# Access Error: 'Export$ is not a valid name.'

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I've been working with an Access DB for months now, and for some reason today my import is throwing a strange error. On importing using a saved import, Access gives me the error:

```
"Export$" is not a valid name. Make sure it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long.
```

My import is a Excel file of roughly 350,000 rows, 12 columns. Every week I run this import with a new weekly Excel file and have never seen this error before. I don't believe I have any invalid names in my column titles ($Export exists nowhere in my sheet.)

How can I fix this or find what row is throwing the error?

EDIT:

The worksheet that is throwing the error is named "WP Items", is reference at C:/SK/WP Items.xlsx. The import draws from the name, which is the same as it is every week - so that confuses me further.

There is no VBA involved here, just running a saved import.

Comment: Error refers to a worksheet name not column name. Check to see if there is a worksheet named `Export`. Also, please post Access VBA code, not just the error statement.

Comment: @Parfait Edited the question to reflect your comment. I am using no VBA, only a saved import. There is no worksheet named Export.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of struggling, the problem was solved.

For anyone else who encounters this slightly cryptic error in the future- the problem was that my imports had changed slightly week-to-week. The fields being imported by the previous saved import weren't exactly the same, so there was an error thrown. Had to delete and recreate the saved import specification, as well as change the table schema to reflect the new data.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.  Every month for 10 year's I import the same file with updated data... I just figured out this problem with trial and error.  On the import file, one of the header row names inadvertently had a space in front of the column name. I deleted the space & its FIXED.